# Classic ASP calling Oracle stored procedure with OraOleadb Driver

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I am facing a very strange problem may be I have missed something.

Here is the scenario, we have an ASP application which uses Oracle 11G as backend database.

We are calling a store stored procedure which is accepting these parameters.

```
PROCEDURE PR_SUMMARY_IN(theAccountId in varchar2,
                        theAwardId in number,
                        theDueDate in varchar2,
                        theSubmittedDate in varchar2,
                        theReportDescription in varchar2,
                        theFormId in varchar2,
                        theReturnCode out number) 
AS
    v_submitted_date date;
BEGIN
      IF theSubmittedDate IS NOT NULL THEN                                    
                v_submitted_date := to_date(theSubmittedDate,'MM/DD/YYYY');--error here         
            ELSE                                                                    
                v_submitted_date := NULL;                                           

            END IF;

       insert into abc (.....) values (....)
    end
```

and the parameter values as below

```
'3407840001'
8714898
'05/09/2016'
'05/09/2016'
'Test'
'1'
```

When I am running this procedure from SQLPlus, it works, but when I am calling it from ASP code, it throws an error

> ORA-20502: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Below is ASP code snapshot

```
due_date = Request.Form("due_date" & i)
        IF Len(due_date) = 0 THEN
            theDueDt = NULL
        ELSE
            theDueDt = "'" & due_date & "'"
        END IF

        submitted_date = Request.Form("submitted_date" & i)
        IF Len(submitted_date) = 0 THEN
            theSubmittedDt = NULL
        ELSE
            theSubmittedDt = "'" & submitted_date & "'"
        END IF

        report_description = Request.Form("report_description" & i)
        IF Len(report_description) = 0 THEN
            theReportDesc = NULL
        ELSE
            theReportDesc = "'" & Replace(report_description,"'","''") & "'"
        END IF

        form_id = Request.Form("form_id" & i)
        IF Len(form_id) = 0 THEN
            theFrmId = NULL
        ELSE
            theFrmId = "'" & Replace(form_id,"'","''") & "'"
        END IF  

        cmd.CommandType = 4
        cmd.CommandText = "deadlines_summary.PR_SUMMARY_IN" 

        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theAccountId", 12, 1, 100, Request.Form ("aid"))
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theAwardId", adNumeric, 1, 100, award_id)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theDueDate", 12, 1, 100, theDueDt)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theSubmittedDate", 12, 1, 100, theSubmittedDt)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theReportDescription", 12, 1, 100, theReportDesc)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theFormId", 12, 1, 100, theFrmId)

        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theReturnCode", 131, 2, 10)


        IF Len(report_description) > 0 THEN    
            set rs = cmd.execute
        END IF
```

Any suggestions please

For testing purpose I have declared local variable as varchar2 in SP and assigned value '12/09/2016' in mm/dd/yyyy format.

and got below log. Before and after.

if value hard coded, it treated without single quote. Wondering how?

```
CREATED_ON----------MSG--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

05/09/2016          1.1 theDueDate '12/09/2016' tmp_theDueDate 12/09/2016 v_due_date

05/09/2016          1.2 theSubmittedDate '11/09/2016' tmp_theSubmittedDate 11/09/2016 v_submitted_date

05/09/2016          2.1 theSubmittedDate '11/09/2016' tmp_theSubmittedDate 11/09/2016 v_submitted_date 2016-11-09 00:00:00

05/09/2016          2.2 theDueDate '12/09/2016' tmp_theDueDate 12/09/2016 v_due_date 2016-12-09 00:00:00
```

Comment: Are you passing in the parameter type appropriate to the parameters of the stored procedure? Can you paste your asp code that builds a command and adds parameters and so on?

Comment: Could you use constants such as `adVarchar` instead of 12 (which is `adVariant`)? What use is 10 for output parameter? Why is `Request.Form ("aid")` not surrounded with quotes?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I have updated my question with some finding. 1.1, 1.2 is before scenario and 2.1,2.2 is after scenario. Hardcoded value treated differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), parameter type `adVariant` (i.e. 12) is not supported by ADO.

You should use constants in order to make your code more readable, e.g.

```
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adCmdStoredProc = 4

Const adVarChar = 200 
Const adNumeric = 131 
Const adChar = 129
Const adBigInt = 20 
Const adInteger = 3

Const adParamInput = 1
Const adParamOutput = 2
Const adParamInputOutput = 3
Const adParamReturnValue = 4

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theAccountId", adVarChar, adParamInput, , Request.Form ("aid"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theAwardId", adNumeric, adParamInput, , award_id)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theDueDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, theDueDt)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theSubmittedDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, theSubmittedDt)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theReportDescription", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, theReportDesc)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theFormId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, theFrmId)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("theReturnCode", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
```

Maybe try this one:

```
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "{CALL deadlines_summary.PR_SUMMARY_IN(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
```

Numeric parameters do not require a size value.

You should also try to use parameter type `adDate` instead of converting the dates into string values.

You must remove the quotes when you use bind parameter, i.e. use simply `theSubmittedDt = submitted_date` instead of `theSubmittedDt = "'" & submitted_date & "'"`.

Comment: sorry I could not saw your post and replied. But any way I will mark your post theSubmittedDt = submitted_date instead of theSubmittedDt = "'" & submitted_date & "'"  as answer. Thanks a lot. But can you tell me why this behavior if possible.

Comment: That's them main purpose of bind parameters (i.e. `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter...`), you don't have to take care about any quoting mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

So here we go. Some how I managed to make above code running by changing below code

FROM

```
       IF Len(due_date) = 0 THEN
            theDueDt = NULL
        ELSE
            theDueDt = "'" & due_date & "'"
        END IF

        submitted_date = Request.Form("submitted_date" & i)
        IF Len(submitted_date) = 0 THEN
            theSubmittedDt = NULL
        ELSE
            theSubmittedDt = "'" & submitted_date & "'"
        END IF
```

TO

```
IF Len(due_date) = 0 THEN
        theDueDt = NULL
    ELSE
        theDueDt = due_date
    END IF

    submitted_date = Request.Form("submitted_date" & i)
    IF Len(submitted_date) = 0 THEN
        theSubmittedDt = NULL
    ELSE
        theSubmittedDt = submitted_date
    END IF
```

Sending parameter value without quote and works. Need to get the root cause and this strange behavior. Thanks for suggestion guys.