# Error: Parameter Type is not supported in ADODB code of classic ASP

Tags: oracle, vbscript, asp-classic

I have written code to insert call parameterized stored procedure written in oracle pl/sql. I have given all parameters properly as displayed in below code.

```vb
 function CallSp(str_id, ref_no, note, userId, strdatestamp, writtenDate)
   Dim strcon2 : set strcon2=server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Dim strcmd2
   Dim sql2
   Dim ReturnVal
   strcon2.Open "Proper Connectionstring provided here"
   sql2 = "Fr_Store_Notes"

   Set strcmd2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   Set strcmd2.ActiveConnection = strCOn2
   strcmd2.CommandText = sql2
   strcmd2.CommandType = 4
   strcmd2.Parameters.Refresh
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_str_id", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_str_id") = str_id
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_ref_no", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_ref_no") = ref_no
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_UserId", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_UserId") = userId
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_note", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_note") = note
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_Datestamp", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_Datestamp") = strdatestamp
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strcmd2.CreateParameter("p_WrittenDate", 12,1)
   strcmd2.Parameters("p_WrittenDate") = writtenDate
   strcmd2.Parameters.Append strCmd2.CreateParameter("p_return", 3, 2)
   strcmd2.Execute
   ReturnVal = strcmd2.Parameters("p_return").Value

   CallSp=ReturnVal
   set strCmd2=Nothing
   strCon2.close
end function
```

But I am receiving error as

> Parameter Type is not supported at the line `strcmd2.Execute`

Database stored procedure is as like below and working fine if we execute it from database

```sql
create or replace
procedure Fr_Store_Notes (
  P_STR_ID IN VARCHAR2,
  p_Ref_no in VARCHAR2,
  P_UserId in VARCHAR2,
  P_Note IN VARCHAR2,
  P_datestamp IN VARCHAR2,
  p_WrittenDate IN VARCHAR2,
  p_return OUT number)
AS
BEGIN
--Expected Code Block is there and working fine
End;
```

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue

Comment: According to [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) *(which is the best resource I've found for data type mapping in ADODB)* `number` in Oracle maps to `adNumeric` which is `131` not `3` so the `p_return` parameter is wrong.

Comment: Answered a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43226393/692942).

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to add the rest of the `Fr_Store_Notes` procedure definition, need to understand what it is doing to work out why ADODB is reporting `ODBC driver does not support the requested properties`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** - Apparently after a bit of research *(as I don't work with Oracle)* ADODB doesn't support `adVariant` *(which is `12`)* and you should use `adVarChar` *(which is `200`)* instead.

See [A: Classic ASP calling Oracle stored procedure with OraOleadb Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37116598/692942)

Leaving the rest of the answer below as it's probably still relevant once this issue is fixed.

---

The cause is of that particular error is usually a mismatch of data type once the ADODB talks to the provider defined by the connection.

Just looking at the procedure definition in Oracle in comparison to your `ADODB.Command` object I can see that the `p_return` parameter appears to be incorrect. I talk about this in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226393/692942) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43214270/692942).

According to [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) *(a great resource for Data Type Mapping in ADO)* `adInteger` *(which is `3`)* maps to `Int` in Oracle not `Number`. Instead, you should use `adNumeric` *(which is `131`)* which should fix that particular error.

Try changing this line

```vb
strcmd2.Parameters.Append strCmd2.CreateParameter("p_return", 3, 2)
```

to

```vb
strcmd2.Parameters.Append strCmd2.CreateParameter("p_return", 131, 2)
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942)
- [A: ADODB.Parameters error '800a0e7c' Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942) *(recommend this to learn how to use `METADATA` in `global.asa` to have ADO Named Constants always available to an ASP Web Application)*

Comment: the above issue is resolved but I am getting error now as "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties"

Comment: @Audumbar On the same line in the code or somewhere else?

Comment: On the same Line  of above my mentioned code it is thrown

Comment: @Audumbar not sure why you have `strcmd2.Parameters.Refresh` to be honest as that is for automatically populating the `Parameters` collection by querying the database beforehand *(not efficient, wouldn't recommend it for production)* but you already defining your parameters using `CreateParameter()` so that is pointless. Nothing else popping out at me, perhaps look at some of the provided links to get a better idea of how to structure the `ADODB.Command`.