# Getting values from PL/SQL executed command in VBScript

Tags: oracle, plsql, vbscript, adodb

I'm currently trying to call a function from oracle database function from VBScript. I want to get the value of the pl/sql function I executed in VBScript, but I don't know how to do that.

let's say my pl/sql function:

```
p_result := x_found_in_y(x, y)
```

(x, y are VARCHAR2 returns p_result BOOLEAN)

so here's a snippet of my script:

```
'Open connection
ConnectionString = "DSN=" & strDSN &";Uid=" & strUID & ";Pwd=" & strPWD & ";"
objConnection.Open(ConnectionString) 

'--- assuming all the variables are initialized

strQuery = 
"DECLARE p_bool BOOLEAN; BEGIN p_bool:= x_found_in_y('employee', 'employee_table'); END;"

Set objResults = objConnection.Execute strQuery
```

But then I don't know how I can get p_bool (which returns boolean) and pass it to a variable in VBScript. I'm guessing this is a simple task, but I'm VERY new to VBScript.

I tried to search from stackoverflow resolved questions, but don't seem to find previous similar cases.

Comment: We don't know what the structure of `x_found_in_y(x, y)` is without having the definition for it, we can only guess based on how you call it. Please [edit] the question and include the definition.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed. It provides all necessary information and code (apart from an error messages, but the problem in the code is quite obvious). The OP tried to find a solution by himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be this:

```
Const adBoolean = 11
Const adVarChar = 200 
Const adNumeric = 131 
Const adChar = 129
Const adBigInt = 20 
Const adInteger = 3

Const adParamInput = 1
Const adParamOutput = 2
Const adParamInputOutput = 3
Const adParamReturnValue = 4

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection

cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN ? := x_found_in_y_NUM(?, ?); END;"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("p_bool", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("x", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "employee")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("y", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "employee_table")
cmd.Execute

Wscript.Echo cmd.Parameters("p_bool").Value
```

As written in my comment you cannot use BOOLEAN data type (as least not for return value). Write another PL/SQL function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x_found_in_y_NUM(x IN VARCHAR2, y IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER AS
BEGIN
    IF x_found_in_y(x, y) then 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    end if;
END;
```

Or modify your function directly, if possible.

The question marks `?` are placeholder for parameters. It is the preferred way to use so called prepared statements with bind parameters. Each `?` maps to one [Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameter-object?view=sql-server-2017). It gives you less trouble with quoting, formatting issues (e.g. for DATE), better performance and more security (google for SQL-Injection)

It is possible to write

```
cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN ? := x_found_in_y_NUM('employee', 'employee_table'); END;"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("p_bool", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Execute
```

for the `IN` parameters, but it is not the recommended way of doing it. I don't think it is possible to use return (or `OUT`) values without bind parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got an error as such:

[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


Line (94): "cmd.Execute". 

Then, I changed adVarchar =200 to adVariant=12, but then I got the follwoing error:

Parameter type is not supported in cmd.Execute

Then I discover this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776948/error-parameter-type-is-not-supported-in-adodb-code-of-classic-asp 
so I cant use adVariant. Now I have no idea as it seems that the datatypes are correct?

Comment: Yes, I was not sure whether you can use non SQL-types (as BOOLEAN) as return value. Try to convert return value to "1" and "0" instead.

Comment: Relevant: [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)

Comment: This is what happens when you answer a question that doesn't provide enough information to answer without ambiguity. Best to get the OP to clarify/provide missing information before posting an answer that will be met with, get this error etc.

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved. 
I made the following changes regarding my errors:

cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN ? := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(x_found_in_y(?, ?)); END;"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("p_bool", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("x", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100, "employee")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("y", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100, "employee_table")
cmd.Execute

sorry, I have to be extra careful with these scripts. I know it can be annoying.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the immediate answers to my questions. Very helpful! I will modify my code as how I need it.